# Panel is overlapping and has a wrong ratio in mplfinance plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

I'm trying to plot a subplot but there are two problems. 
#1 The `panel_ratio` setting `(6,1)` is unnoticed. 
#2 The y axis of the top panel juts down and overlaps the y axis of the bottom panel, so that the bars are trimmed in the top panel

What is wrong with the code?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import mplfinance as mpf

times = pd.date_range(start='2022-01-01', periods=50, freq='ms')

def get_rsi(df, rsi_period):
    chg = df['close'].diff(1)
    gain = chg.mask(chg<0,0)
    loss = chg.mask(chg>0,0)
    avg_gain = gain.ewm(com=rsi_period-1, min_periods=rsi_period).mean()
    avg_loss = loss.ewm(com=rsi_period-1, min_periods=rsi_period).mean()
    rs = abs(avg_gain/avg_loss)
    rsi = 100 - (100/(1+rs))
    return rsi


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3000, 3100, (50, 1)), columns=['open'])
df['high'] = df.open+5
df['low'] = df.open-2
df['close'] = df.open
df['rsi14'] = get_rsi(df, 14)
df.set_index(times, inplace=True)
lows_peaks = df.low.nsmallest(5).index

fig = mpf.figure(style="charles",figsize=(7,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)

ap0 = [ mpf.make_addplot(df['rsi14'],color='g', ax=ax2, ylim=(10,90), panel=1) ]
mpf.plot(df, ax=ax1, ylim=(2999,3104), addplot=ap0, panel_ratios=(6,1))

mpf.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it is easier to use a panel instead of an external axis. I tried your code and could not improve it. For a detailed reference on panels, see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/panels.ipynb).

```
# fig = mpf.figure(style="charles", figsize=(7,8))
# ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
# ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)

ap0 = mpf.make_addplot(df[['rsi14']], color='g', ylim=(10,90), panel=1)
mpf.plot(df[['open','high', 'low','close']], addplot=ap0, ylim=(2999,3104), panel_ratios=(6,1), style='charles')

mpf.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It works with the sample code, but unfortunately not with my real code, because I forgot to mention that I need it in the animation function for a real time plot. But that's my bad